# If $\vec{AA_1} + \vec{BB_1} + \vec{CC_1} = 0$ prove that the triangle is equlateral.

Tags: geometry, triangles

The problem states that if $AA_1, BB_1$ and $CC_1$ are the altitudes of the triangle $\bigtriangleup ABC$ and $\vec{AA_1} + \vec{BB_1} + \vec{CC_1} = 0$ then the triangle is equilateral.

My solution:

WLOG we can assume that $AB \geq BC \geq CA$. This implies that $CC_1 \leq AA_1 \leq BB_1$ (i).From $\vec{AA_1} + \vec{BB_1} + \vec{CC_1} = 0$ we can create a triangle whose edges are the segments $AA_1, BB_1$ and $CC_1$. Furthermore since $AA_1 \perp BC$, $BB_1 \perp AC$ and $CC_1 \perp AB$ this triangle is similar to the triangle $\bigtriangleup ABC$. Hence:
$$\frac{CC_1}{AB}=\frac{AA_1}{BC}=\frac{BB_1}{AC} \Longrightarrow CC_1\geq AA_1 \geq BB_1$$
But with (i) this implies that $CC_1=AA_1=BB_1$ and it follows that $AB=BC=CA$.

qed

My problem is that I am looking for something more elegant and easier to understand for people with a basic understanding of vectors (basic properties, addition, scalar multiplication etc).

Answer (score 2):

Possible way: let vectors $a,\ b,\ a-b$ be the sides of the triangle.
Then the two altitudes, corresponding to $a,b$ are $-a+\frac{(a,b)}{b^2}b,\ -b+\frac{(a,b)}{a^2}a$.
Let's find the third as $ta+(1-t)b$:
$$(ta+(1-t)b)(a-b)=0$$
$$ta^2-t(a,b)+(1-t)(a,b)-(1-t)b^2=0$$
$$t(a^2-(a,b)-(a,b)+b^2)+(a,b)-b^2=0$$
$$t=\frac{-b(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}$$
And the altitude: $$\frac{-b(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}a+\frac{-a(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}b$$
Let's combine: $$-a+\frac{(a,b)}{b^2}b-b+\frac{(a,b)}{a^2}a+\frac{-b(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}a+\frac{-a(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}b=0$$
We see it's a linear combination of basis vectors $a,b$, so it's coefficients must be $=0$:
$$\begin{cases}
-1+\frac{(a,b)}{a^2}+\frac{-b(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}=0\\
-1+\frac{(a,b)}{b^2}+\frac{-a(a-b)}{(a-b)^2}=0
\end{cases}$$
Hence we derive $a^2=b^2=(a,b)$
P.S. all the products are dot products.

Comment: Good solution. Thanks. Working with only 2 of the vectors since they are linearly independent came into my mind.

Comment: Sometimes it turns out to be hard to find an appropriate basis that keeps things simple, especially for a arbitrary quadrilateral, e.g. Crux 2177. However, this is not the case :) Welcome. :)